# Showing No of Rows in Gridview according to Selected value from Dropdown

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Let, I already have retrieved necessary information from database, using one grid view to show that information, and it successfully done.

Now i want to do thing like , using one drop-down which contains some digits.

According to that selected value from drop-down i want to show only those no of records in grid-view. like If I have retrieved 100 records from database and wants to show only 30 of them.

Is it possible ??

If yes then please suggest any solution..

Am not very much familiar with grid-view, and frankly speaking have not tried for this functioning .

here Is Code behind  :

// it loads the gridview

```
   public void fillGrid()
   {
    lbl_hldId.Text = Request.QueryString["qname"].ToString();
    clsUserTB objuser = new clsUserTB();
    objuser.User_Id = (lbl_hldId.Text).ToString();
    objuser.ex_Date = DateTime.Now;
    DataSet ds = clsAdminLogic.empMonthLogs(objuser);
    lbl_Id.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["User_Id"].ToString();
    lbl_name.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    lbl_contact.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Contact"].ToString();
    grdv_mnthRec.Visible = true;
    grdv_mnthRec.DataSource = ds;
    grdv_mnthRec.DataBind();
    if (Convert.ToInt32(ddl_digits.SelectedItem.ToString()) != null)
        grdv_mnthRec.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddl_digits.SelectedValue);
}
```

// Paging event

```
protected void grdv_mnthRec_PageIndexChanging1(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
   {
     grdv_mnthRec.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
     grdv_mnthRec.DataBind();
     fillGrid();
   }
```

// Drop-downindex change event

```
protected void ddl_digits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   fillGrid();
}
```

If am doing something wrong .. then please let me know

Comment: you can bind the grid view again in dropdownselected indexchange according to the selected value

Comment: @dazzlingkumar can you please explain little more

Comment: you can bind the gridview in dropdown selectedindexchanged event according to the dropdown value ,  could you understand this

Comment: yes and have tried same but its not as per my expectation, let me edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You May Try This:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        fillGrid();
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, ("Select"));
    }
}
int size = 0;
public void fillGrid()
{
    lbl_hldId.Text = Request.QueryString["qname"].ToString();
    clsUserTB objuser = new clsUserTB();
    objuser.User_Id = (lbl_hldId.Text).ToString();
    objuser.ex_Date = DateTime.Now;
    DataSet ds = clsAdminLogic.empMonthLogs(objuser);
    lbl_Id.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["User_Id"].ToString();
    lbl_name.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
    lbl_contact.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Contact"].ToString();
    grdv_mnthRec.Visible = true;
    grdv_mnthRec.DataSource = ds;
    grdv_mnthRec.DataBind();
}
protected void grdv_mnthRec_PageIndexChanging1(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grdv_mnthRec.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grdv_mnthRec.DataBind();
    fillGrid();
}
protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddl.SelectedIndex!=0)
    {
        size = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
        grdv_mnthRec.PageSize = size;
        fillGrid();
    }
    else
    {
        size = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to :

1.) Just limit  the Number of Rows displayed with NO more links
    (NO Paging ) to see next set of records ? Check **METHOD I**

OR

2.) Implement GridView Paging functionality with the [**`PageSize`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagesize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) set to the value selected in dropdownlist ? Check **METHOD II**

**METHOD I**:: *No Paging*

```
protected void ddl_digits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int maxRecordsToDisplay = Convert.ToInt32(ddl_digits.SelectedValue);
   fillGrid(maxRecordsToDisplay, false);
}
```

And your FillGrid method :

```
public void fillGrid(int maxRecordsToDisplay, bool paging)
{
 DataSet ds = clsAdminLogic.empMonthLogs(objuser);

// if NO paging is required, filter the rows in dataset
 if(!paging) 
 {
 IEnumerable<DataRow> filteredRecords= ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Take(maxRecordsToDisplay);
 grdv_mnthRec.DataSource = filteredRecords.AsDataView();
 }
 // if paging is enabled, set the PageSize property
 else 
   {
      GridView1.PageSize = maxRecordsToDisplay;
      grdv_mnthRec.DataSource = ds;
   }

      grdv_mnthRec.DataBind();
}
```

**METHOD II** : With Paging enabled , `fillgrid()` method will be same as above

```
<asp:gridview id="grdv_mnthRec" runat="server" allowpaging="True" ../>
```

// Paging event

```
protected void grdv_mnthRec_PageIndexChanging1(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
   {
     grdv_mnthRec.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
     int maxRecordsToDisplay = Convert.ToInt32(ddl_digits.SelectedValue);
     fillGrid(maxRecordsToDisplay, true);
   }
```

// dropdownlist selected index changed event

```
protected void ddl_digits_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int maxRecordsToDisplay = Convert.ToInt32(ddl_digits.SelectedValue);
   fillGrid(maxRecordsToDisplay, true);
}
```